# How to Insert html in custom field (type TextArea) via API

Tags: custom-fields, api, html

I have a custom field with data type 'Note' and field type 'TextArea'. When I insert a value using the CiviCRM interface, I can insert text via an editor, and bold text gets displayed as bold, italic etc.

Now I want to put html in this same field using the API, but the problem is that any html characters are converted to html entities when inserted.

```
  $params = array(
  'contact_id' => $contact_id,
  'entity_id' => $contact_id,
  'custom_' . $content_field_id => '<div class="note_content">' . implode('</div><div class="note_content">', $data['note_content']) . '</div>',
);
$create_note_result = $spcivi->api('CustomValue', 'create', $params);
```

html send via api:

```
<div class="note_content"><strong>Vette</strong> tekst is toegestaan!</div><div class="note_content"><em>Shuine</em> ook!</div>
```

result content in field:

```
&lt;div class="note_content"&gt;&lt;strong&gt;Vette&lt;/strong&gt; tekst is toegestaan!&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div class="note_content"&gt;&lt;em&gt;Shuine&lt;/em&gt; ook!&lt;/div&gt;
```

Is there a way to insert html without the html characters being converted to html entities? Using the field type TextArea becomes quite useless when not html can be inserted.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried any of the following before submitting the TextArea?

1. Highlight the code portion and Ctrl + K or Command K
2. Indent the code lines 4 spaces
3. Use backtics ' your html '
4. Use code tag `<code>your html</code>`

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be unsupported in the API, which encodes all HTML values. I've created a JIRA issue to request this functionality: https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-21572